# What is best way to refresh data in first TableView when editing its data in a second TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm confused about the exact requirements in order to refresh data in your original TableView when you are editing the data in another TableView. Can someone simply state what the correct way to do this is?

I have an app based on the DrillDown tutorial [here](https://github.com/mea36/duca2012_group7/tree/master/DrillDownApp) that displays my favorite quotes. The quotes are stored in a sqlite db which is loaded when the app starts. My RootViewController shows the categories of quotes and the data is provided by a QuotesAppDelegate.

On my RootViewController there is an edit button that displays a SettingsViewController which allows you to toggle which categories will be displayed and which will not.

In the click_Saved method I update the database with any changes that are made and attempt to refresh the RootViewController from this SettingsViewController. I update the RootViewController's data array `cvc.categories` and the underlying database here `[sub setActive:s.active]`. I know that the database is properly updating because when I restart the app, the changes are made in the RootViewController. However I want the changes to immediately show up when I click_Saved and it dismisses the SettingsViewController and returns back to RootViewController.

I have tried the [self.tableView reloadData], tried notifications, and searched SO for solutions and must be missing some fundamental issue, which I would appreciate some direction on.

```
- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {

    RootViewController *cvc = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

    QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    for (Subject *s in selectedTabs){

        NSLog(@"--   Set selected subject %@-%@ to %ld", s.category_title, s.title, (long)s.active);

        //UPDATE THE ACTIVE STATUS ON THE SELECTED SUBJECTS
        [s setActiveStatus:s.active];

        //UPDATE ARRAY
        for (Subject *sub in appDelegate.subjects){

            if (sub.subject_id == s.subject_id){
                [sub setActive:s.active];
            }

        }

    }

    //RELOAD WHOLE DATABASE
    [appDelegate populateFromDatabase];

    cvc.categories = [appDelegate activeCategories];
    cvc.subjects = [appDelegate activeSubjects];
    [cvc.tableView reloadData];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"refreshData"
     object:nil
     userInfo:nil//userInfoDictionary
     ];

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];

}
```

**EDIT:** I found the `numberOfRowsInSection` is getting called multiple times and looks like it is correctly updating and then reverting back as you can see here:

```
2015-11-14 11:38:55.086 Quotes[49115:2751005] ~~~numberOfRowsInSection: 15
2015-11-14 11:38:55.086 Quotes[49115:2751005] ~~~numberOfRowsInSection: 16
2015-11-14 11:38:55.087 Quotes[49115:2751005] ~~~numberOfRowsInSection: 15
2015-11-14 11:38:55.533 Quotes[49115:2751005] ~~~numberOfRowsInSection: 16
```

---

Comment: you are pushing to second table view ?

Comment: did u try reloading the table on viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear ? It will be called when you come back to first table view!!!

Comment: Yes pushing to second table view where all categories are displayed and a check mark if they are active or not. I'll try reload on viewWillAppear now.

Comment: I tried reloading the table on viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear and it is still not reloading the data.  See new edit in post above. I found the tableView is getting updated but is being reverted back.

Comment: In my RootViewController I was calling [self.tableView reloadData] under viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. I commented these out, but still got same results.

Comment: The basic technique is: 1) update your model, 2) let the interested parties know the model changed.  The reason that's so general is because there are so many ways of doing each.  If you were using Core Data  with NSFetchedResultsControllers, for example, the framework would be doing the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: This is still unresolved. I've tried the above suggestions. Anything obviously wrong with the above code that would make the refresh not work?